# How to parse trigger messages from initiation queue (.Net)?

Tags: .net, triggers, ibm-mq, message, mq

I write my own trigger monitor. It will listen to initiation queue and will get messages from it. I'd like to parse these messages. Are there any classes, methods in `amqmdnet.dll` that can help me with it? Or where can I find a format of trigger messages?

Answer (score 1):

> I write my own trigger monitor.

Why would you want to do that?  IBM supplies a trigger monitor with MQ.  Or do you mean to say you are writing an application that will be started by the trigger monitor?

Either way, the init message that the queue manager puts in the initialization queue is documented in the WMQ InfoCenter and the parameters passed to a trigger/started application are also documented in WMQ InfoCenter.